# System.Data.OracleClient Vs. ODP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, database, oracle, oracle11g

Which of the above should I use. Please let me know with respect to the following aspects:

- Efficiency
- Licensing (are both free? )
- Ease of development
- Compatibility with .NET datatypes etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the only way you should go is the ODP.NET, the OracleClient has been deprecated and will not be supported any longer in future versions of the .NET Framework.

check here: [Microsoft OracleClient Deprecated](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/06/oracleclient_deprecated)

**Edit:** from the linked article:

[Oracle's free Oracle Data Provider for .NET (ODP.NET)](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html)

ODP.NET 11g is compatbile with all versions of Oracle Database back to 9.2, and multiple versions can coexist in a single OS

Comment: thanks. Is ODP.NET free or do i have to pay for it?

Comment: @ria http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/free-088006.html

Comment: Multiple versions of ODP in the same environment is very dangerous.  While it is supported by Oracle - it does not play well with .Net and should be avoided.

Comment: Wrong. Multiple versions of ODP on same machine is no big deal, you just need to know what you are doing. Make sure Oracle Client architecture matches ODP.NET and you will be fine. I run multiple versions of ODP.NET with multiple architectures and different apps are using different combinations of these. Most common problem is that people either forget to install the Oracle Client in the first place, or that they install 32 bit Oracle client and 64-bit ODP (or vice versa). Your statement likely reflects some bad experience you had in the past based on not understanding this.

Comment: The second most common problem is that people don't understand how .net binding redirection works. If you build a project with reference to ODP.NET 4.102.1.0 but somebody installs on machine with ODP 4.112.2.0 you need an `assemblyBindingRedirect` in app.config (or web.config or whatever) to tell your app that even though it expects `oldVersion` it is OK to actually use `newVersion` of that assembly. (Oracle has backwards version schema: 4.112.2.0 means .NET 4, Oracle 11.2 R2 PL0)

Comment: @nothingisnecessary you are right, however ODP.NET itself loads different native DLL from Oracle directory (e.g. `oci.dll`), so you have to tweak your `%PATH%` environment in order to make it working. Version of Oracle native DLL's have to match **exactly** the version of loaded ODP.NET, otherwise you will get an *"The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client"* error. So, having multiple versions of ODP.NET can be a challenge.